# How to escape ampersand in MS SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table named tblCandy with an XML field named CandySpecs.  When I try to add a value containing an ampersand (&) I get the error:

```
UPDATE tblCandy SET OrigOtherData.modify ('insert <BrandName>M&Ms</BrandName> as first into (CandySpecs/Table)[1]') WHERE RecordID = 1


Msg 2282, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
XQuery [tblCandy.CandySpecs.modify()]: Invalid entity reference
```

I’ve tried various escape sequences with no luck:

```
/&
\&
&&
```

There is a lot of guidance out there on this issue and I’m wondering if there is one best way to address this problem.

Comment: As it's XML I would assume it wants `&amp;` - worth a try anyway

Comment: Try select 'a&z' col1 for XML path('x')

Comment: It does like `&amp;` but I was wondering if there was a way to not use that.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a much better way to deal with this:

```
UPDATE tblCandy SET OrigOtherData.modify ('insert <BrandName><![CDATA[M&Ms]]></BrandName> as first into (CandySpecs/Table)[1]') WHERE RecordID = 1
```

Explanation: the CDATA tag tells the XML to ignore character markup for this block of data.

Related StackOverflow question (not strictly a dupe, but would be worth reading if you're not familiar with this): [What does <![CDATA[]]> in XML mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2784183/what-does-cdata-in-xml-mean)

This will bypass not only the `&`, but also other potentially breaking pieces of data such as `<` and `>` that could potentially exist within the data you're dealing with.

Answer (score 0):

Special symbols in SQL server are being escaped with `\`

in your example statement would look following:

```
UPDATE tblCandy SET OrigOtherData.modify ('insert <BrandName>M\&Ms</BrandName> as first into (CandySpecs/Table)[1]') WHERE RecordID = 1
```

Comment: Tried both back and forward slash and that didn't work. SSMS didn't like it.

Answer (score 0):

Using `&amp;` instead of just `&`.
I found the answer on this article: http://www.techrepublic.com/article/beware-of-the-ampersand-when-using-xml/

Answer (score -1):

```
SET NOCOUNT ON
GO

CREATE TABLE tblCandy ( Id INT, Brandname XML )
GO

INSERT INTO tblCandy VALUES ( 1, '<Brandname >test</Brandname >' )
GO

SELECT 'before', * FROM tblCandy

UPDATE tblCandy 
SET Brandname.modify('replace value of (//Brandname/text())[1]
with string("as first into")')
WHERE Id = 1

SELECT 'After', * FROM tblCandy
GO

DROP TABLE tblCandy
GO
```